# Can't call a static method from another class even though it is imported

Tags: java, class

My main file:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import Windows;


public class Main{

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Windows.createShowGUI(1);

     }
}
```

The other file:

```
package order_java;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Windows {
    public static void addComponentsToHomePane(Container pane){
        //Refer to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html
        //Declaring and linking logo and its label
        ImageIcon logo = new ImageIcon("img/mindnew.png");
        Image image = logo.getImage(); //Resize Image
        Image newimg = image.getScaledInstance(100, 100,  java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH); // scale it the smooth way  
        logo = new ImageIcon(newimg);  // transform it back
        JLabel logoLabel = new JLabel ("Supermind T-Shirts");
        logoLabel.setFont(new Font("",Font.PLAIN,22)); //Set font style and size
        logoLabel.setIcon(logo);
        //Adding to the panel
        pane.add(logoLabel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

        //Nested FlowLayout Panel in main pane, refer to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/flow.html
        JPanel midPanel = new JPanel();
        //Adding buttons to pane
        JButton button1 = new JButton("Staff Member");
        button1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,40));
        JButton button2 = new JButton("Customer");
        button2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,40));
        midPanel.add(button1);
        midPanel.add(new JLabel("or"));
        midPanel.add(button2);
        //Adding nested panel to main pane
        pane.add(midPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);


    }
    public static void addComponentsToPane(Container pane){
        ImageIcon logo = new ImageIcon("img/mindnew.png");
        Image image = logo.getImage(); //Resize Image
        Image newimg = image.getScaledInstance(40, 40,  java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH); // scale it the smooth way  
        logo = new ImageIcon(newimg);  // transform it back
        JLabel logoLabel = new JLabel ("");
        logoLabel.setFont(new Font("",Font.PLAIN,20)); //Set font style and size
        logoLabel.setIcon(logo);
        //Set cart button
        JButton btnCart = new JButton("");
        ImageIcon cart = new ImageIcon("img/cart.png");
        image = cart.getImage(); //Resize Image
        newimg = image.getScaledInstance(30, 30,  java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH); // scale it the smooth way  
        cart = new ImageIcon(newimg);
        btnCart.setIcon(cart);
        //PAGE_START
        JPanel topPane=new JPanel();
        topPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(topPane,BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        topPane.add(logoLabel);
        topPane.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
        topPane.add(btnCart);
        //PAGE_END add Back button
        JPanel btmPane=new JPanel();
        btmPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(btmPane,BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        JButton btnBack = new JButton("");
        btnBack.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(35,35));
        ImageIcon back = new ImageIcon("img/back.png");
        image = back.getImage(); //Resize Image
        newimg = image.getScaledInstance(30, 30,  java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH); // scale it the smooth way  
        back = new ImageIcon(newimg);
        btnBack.setIcon(back);
        btmPane.add(btnBack);

        //Adding to the panel
        pane.add(btmPane , BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        pane.add(topPane, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    }
    public static createShowGUI(int n){
        //Set new frame
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Custom T-Shirt Shop");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(500,500);
        if (n==1) addComponentsToHomePane(frame.getContentPane()); //adding the panels
        else addComponentsToPane(frame.getContentPane());
        //Display the window
        frame.setVisible(true);
        }
}
```

When compiling, I get this error:

```
The method createShowGUI(int) is undefined for the type Windows
```

What caused this issue? This used to be just 1 file and it ran fine and was the same except the createShowGUI method was private since main was in the same class. These problems arose after refactoring. (I don't know what else to type here I'm just filling out required word count.)

Comment: You lost `void` in the method's declaration.

Comment: Oh that worked..weird, it worked before refactoring without the void. Thank you.

Comment: The code as shown won't even compile `Windows`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to import `order_java.Windows`
Edit:

> public static createShowGUI(int n)

Something is wrong here... Do you see the missing return type? It has to be
`public static void createShowGUI(int n)` 
And you will have to remove `package order_java;`, if both are in an unnamed (=default) packag

Comment: That made no difference. I should've made it clear that they were in the same path.